gtk_window_move() does not work on OpenSuse 15.5 64 bits GTK 3.0
It seems as gtk_window_move() no longer works on OpenSuse 15.5 64 bits using GTK 3.0
Is there a way to make it work ?
many thanks
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK3");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 100);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(window), 100, 100);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    app = gtk_application_new("org.example.windowposition", 
                            G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}

Build it this way:
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` test.c -otest


Work for me in OpenSUSE 15.6.

Works fine on OpenSUSE 15.6 and Linux Mint 23.  gcc-13 -o tt $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) tt.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0).   You should edit the question and add the example code to the question.

Does not work on WSL OpenSuse 15.6 :-(

Everytime it runs on WSL OpenSuse 15.6 the window is shown on a different location thus gtk_window_move() is not working

If you look at the documentation of gtk_window_move, the first paragraph says "Asks the [window manager][gtk-X11-arch] to move window to the given position. Window managers are free to ignore this; most window managers ignore requests for initial window positions (instead using a user-defined placement algorithm) and honor requests after the window has already been shown." Thus, it's likely it works only on X11, not on wayland; not sure what WSL does.

yes, I am aware of it, but we were able to do it using GTK 2 and now we need it for GTK 3. Looking for a workaround

Ok, we found a workaround. Execute the app this way:
GDK_BACKEND=x11 ./test

export GDK_BACKEND=x11
